# Azure AD B2C incorrect "permissions" to retrieve token

Tags: azure, authentication, postman, openid-connect, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to get an access token back from an Azure B2C instance by using postman.

I have been following the Microsoft docs for how to do this (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/access-tokens) but keep getting the below error when hitting the /token endpoint -

```
{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "AADB2C90205: This application does not have sufficient permissions against this web resource to perform the operation.\r\nCorrelation ID: 544ba4c7-08e3-4206-9957-3783fa0240e4\r\nTimestamp: 2020-11-06 15:29:17Z\r\n"
}
```

Like in the docs, I make two web calls, the first is to the authorize end point to get the code needed.

[image]

I took the above generated URL and pasted it into a browser. This takes me to a login screen and I login as the test user in B2C that I have created. This returns a code in the browser URL. This so far seems to be as intended.

[image]

I then use the code in the browser to make the below call to the /token endpoint. I always receive the error posted at the beginning of this post when making this request regarding an "invalid grant_type" and insufficient permissions. I should be returned an access token.

[image]

The search results for this issue lead me to believe this is to do with scopes.

I think the scopes should be claimed using the Application ID URI listed at the top right of the app registration, from reading the documentation. I use the same scope on both Auth and Token calls. One of the two below options are what I believe should work but I have tried numerous different versions with the exact same permission error given.

https://.onmicrosoft.com//openid
https://.onmicrosoft.com//openid offline_access

I don't know if there is something additional I need to do within the API permissions page for this to work?
[image]

Would really appreciate any help in things to try here because I've been down the same rabbit hole of suggestions quite a few times now.

Comment: Have you exposed the APIs protected by Azure?

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you :)

Comment: If you have any questions, I will answer you as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

The Scopes provide in the request URL needs to have `openid offline_access`. You can use below query by updating the required fields using Postman

```
POST https://XXXX.b2clogin.com/XXXX.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_susisignin/oauth2/v2.0/token?
grant_type=authorization_code
&client_id=f209c17f-b0b2-4954-XXXX
&scope=https://XXXX.onmicrosoft.com/api/read openid offline_access
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&code=
&client_secret=5f4Xd34Y8XX
```

[image]

When you make a request with out aleast one permission among `openid offline_access` the scope it will fail with privileges issue like below.

[image]

When you see the document at the end of the [Scope section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/access-tokens#scopes) it was mentioned that *the call succeeds if at least one permission is granted.*

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common error. Judging from the screenshots you provided, your **client application** lacks **api application** customization permissions.

I try to reproduce your problem:
[image]

Next, you only need to grant your expose API permissions to the client application, and then grant the **admin consent**.
[image]

[image]

Request token:

[image]

Parse the token and you will see your customized permissions:

[image]